# Inverted Triangle

Tags: loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I have a project due where I have to draw an inverted triangle using the for loop, however I have to use the word that the person inputed to make the triangle.

So... the output should look like this...

```
Enter a word:  hello
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

however...
mine looks like this

```
Enter a word: hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

The code I printed looks like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a word");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String a = keyboard.nextLine();
int rows = a.length()-1;

for(int i = rows; i > 0; i--){
  for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

I tried to search up how to fix it online, but the only thing that comes up is how to make triangles using * signs, but that doesn't seem to work when using words.

If anyone could help me figure out to get the above result it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to print the first `n` characters of `a`? You could do one loop where `i` goes from `a.length()` to 1, and at each step of the loop, you print a line with the first `i` characters of `a`.

Comment: Try to delete the second for-loop and use `System.out.println(a.substring(0,i))`

Comment: Matthias Fripp gave you the answer. If you don't know how to do it, ask. We could write it for you but that wouldn't help you learn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code:

```
for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

You haven't modified the string to be printed in this for loop. It would be more effective to use String.charAt() to modify the output

Here is my modified code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Eneter a word: ");
    String word = sc.next();
    
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<word.length()-i;j++){
            System.out.print(word.charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```